# Message Processor Deactivate After FAULT

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

When there is a "FAULT" and "max.delivery.attempts" processes the configured number of times and even then the process continues in "FAULT" logo in the following section "Message Processor Turns" without manual intervention it activates again? The fact that the "Message Processor" DISABLED can not impact the reading of new messages in JMS queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the Message store and process story implemented in the way to served as First Come First Out basis it is not possible to skip the message that got fault and continue the message flow.

Nevertheless up coming release has a new [improvement](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2908) where you can drop the message out from the queue after x number of fail attempts. Having said that, it is not good practice while you do the schedule and process.

To understand further about [Message-stores and Message-processors](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/01/guaranteed-delivery-with-Message-Store-Message-Processor%20/) read on the given article

In order to avoid this situation you can use the Sampling processor and send the message to back-end. Sample process will immediately remove it from the queue and process further. If the delivery of the message is failed or if you find fault you can re added in to store in Fault sequence.

Comment: If I remove the max.delivery.attempts the "Forward Message Processor" always going to retry later and no sera disabled? I do not know if I remove the parameter would work or if I should put the value -1.

Comment: Since default retry is infinity,even if you remove the max.delivery.attempts property or put -1 behavior would be same.